# Deployment to iis 7 breaks mvc forms auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7

Im in a bit of a pickle with mvc forms auth.

Using iis7 and mvc 4.

I have the following controller.

```
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize(Roles = "Control")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index2()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

The view of index is as follows:

```
    @HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("control")
    @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
    @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
    @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType
```

I also have an aspx page with the following:

```
    <div> <%=HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("control") %> </div>
    <div> <%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %> </div>
    <div> <%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %> </div>
    <div> <%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType %> </div>
```

Now on my local pc everything worked fine and dandy and HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("control") is true on both the view and the aspx page when logged in.

When I deploy to the server however the view says that "HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("control")" is false and the aspx page says its true. 
For the same user ie:
"HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated/Name" is the same on both pages.

I'm assuming that it has something to do with modules config. My config currently uses:

```
    <modules>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        <remove name="BundleModule" />
        <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
        <remove name="BasicAuthentication" />
        <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
        <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
        <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
```

Without the modules with preconditions equaling "" mvc doesn't resolve.

Note: The internet seems to think that runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is the magic bullet but this dosent work for me my requests just timeout.

Another Note: Upon deployment there where a bunch of files missing from the gac that i had to manually replace, dont think its related.

In summary when i navigate to index i get booted to the login page on live server on dev I don't. :(

Has anyone seems a similar situation? 
Or has an idea of what i'm stuffing up?

**EDIT 1:**

Re reading this after sleep seems a bit unclear to me. So I will summarize again. Not entirely sure if i should remove the unclear content above or leave it in :S.

Upon deployment:

- When I navigate to Index on the test controller i get bumped to the login.
- When I navigate to Index2 on the test controller IsInRole("control") is false.
- When I navigate to the aspx page is true.
- Both Index2 and the aspx are the same user.

In dev enviroment:

- When I navigate to Index on the test controller it resolves and IsInRole("control") is true.
- When I navigate to Index2 on the test controller IsInRole("control") is true.
- When I navigate to the aspx page is true.
- Both Index2 and the aspx are the same user.

**EDIT 2:**
I have added in

```
    </br>
    @{
        var cookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
    }
    @authTicket.UserData
```

In all cases this returns "control" and yet still IsInRole("control") returns false :S

**EDIT 3:**
Ok so using my mad skillz I have worked around the issue by overriding the attribute. Im not supplying this as an answer as its a hack and I don't like it and I would like to know why this doesn't work correctly. But the BEAuthorize instead of AuthorizeAttribute my auth works perfectly.

```
    public class BEAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string _roles;
        private string[] _rolesSplit = new string[0];
        private string _users;
        private string[] _usersSplit = new string[0];


        public string Users
        {
            get { return _users ?? String.Empty; }
            set
            {
                _users = value;
                _usersSplit = SplitString(value);
            }
        }

        public string Roles
        {
            get { return _roles ?? String.Empty; }
            set
            {
                _roles = value;
                _rolesSplit = SplitString(value);
            }
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
            var user = httpContext.User;

            if (authTicket == null)
                return false;

            var currentUserRoles = SplitString(authTicket.UserData);

            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var roleMatchFound = _rolesSplit.Any(
                attributeRole => currentUserRoles.Any(
                    currentUserRole => String.Equals(
                        currentUserRole, 
                        attributeRole, 
                        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
                )));

            return roleMatchFound || _rolesSplit.Length == 0;
        }

        internal static string[] SplitString(string original)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
            {
                return new string[0];
            }

            var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                        let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                        where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                        select trimmed;
            return split.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

**Edit 4: **

I had the exact same issue with ApiController(s) I had to apply the same hacky solution.